# Remove map data from array from firestore

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How should i remove map from firestore array?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5MPc.png)

Here is my structue
address_list (array)
0:map #and map contains string data
**1:map**

Now i want to delete some map of my array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.